# Where can I find a contact form for Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: forms, contact-page, bootstrap

Where can I find a working contact form for Twitter Bootstrap? I'm using simple template with build in fields for Name, Email and Message. (I don't have any knowledge of PHP)

Thank you.
Nina

Answer (score 1):

The bootstrap only helps you design an existing forms. It will not help you do the programming involved.

If you want a working contact form and don't have php knowledge , consider using 3rd party forms to do the work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any suggestions for a realiable 3rd party form?

Comment: check google forms http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=87809

Answer (score 0):

Twitter Bootstrap doesn't come with a functioning contact form. It does however come with many existing styles for all poplar form fields.

The easiest way to create a functioning contact form using Twitter Bootstrap would be to remove the CSS styles from any functioning contact form and apply styles from twitter bootstrap.